# Product list page in webapp: use database queries or search engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, web-applications, solr, search-engine

I'm looking for best practices designing a scalable web application (using rails), where products are listed on a page with features like searching in title and description, selecting a category and sorting.

I see two options:

1. Use search engine (Solr, IndexTank) only when user searches for keywords, for everything else query database.
2. Use search engine for everything: the default list (list without any user action), displaying categories, ordering and obv. searching.

And there are two sub-options:

1. retrieve ids from search engine, then query db (or cache?) for data
2. store in search engine all data needed to display a product and retrieve all relevant data when searching

What do you think? Thanks in advance..

Comment: really not enough information to give a recommendation.  for sites that are very public and crawl-able, just using google custom search will generally be better than what you implement.

Comment: I disagree with Kalendae. These are common design questions, which I expand on in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note that my response here will be scoped by my experience with Solr…)

For your first set of questions: I'd recommend doing as much searching as possible through your search engine. Solr can handle all of your category filtering and faceting just fine. Any page that you might want to combine with keyword-based searching, faceting, and so on would do just as well to go through Solr entirely.

In Solr, a wildcard query that's sorted on a field value isn't necessarily the most efficient kind of query (it sorts all matching records at query time before discarding all but the first page), but it shouldn't be too terrible. Keep an eye on that initial results page, and if necessary, just serve up something more interesting straight from SQL, or a cache, so as to leave the real searching to Solr.

Remember, this particular case isn't really a "search results" page if no search has been done, it's a "blank slate" page. Design accordingly.

For the latter set of questions, both are common and valid patterns, at least with Solr, and come down to client implementation. For example, the Sunspot ruby client for Solr will lazily-load related ActiveRecord objects when you call its search object's `results` method. This is really handy when rendering views with full-fledged ActiveRecord objects.

However, Sunspot also provides access to the raw stored values returned by Solr, so you can save a trip to the database if you're short on milliseconds.

Have fun!